# Node/Meteor retrieves local IP to be 127.0.1.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, dns

In Meteor.js, I did the equivalent of

```
 require('dns').lookup(require('os').hostname()
```

Why does it return `127.0.1.1` instead of the actual LAN IP?

Answer (score 0):

[`dns.lookup()` looks in `/etc/hosts`, the other `dns` methods do not](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/5ff59453a483a43f1563504989f8e2d0ec253de1). So it's probably picking up a `hosts` entry for your machine's name that is typically set to `127.x.x.x`.

Network interface information is available in the return value of [`os.networkInterfaces()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/os.html#os_os_networkinterfaces).